# How to solve inequality $x(2-x^2)\ge0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve this inequality:

$$x(2-x^2)\geq 0$$

I know the answer is: $$x \geq \sqrt{2}, - \sqrt{2} \leq x \leq 0$$ But why? We get that $x \geq 0$ and $x \geq \sqrt{2}, x \leq - \sqrt{2}$ Why then the answer is not $x \geq \sqrt{2}$, when its the intersection area?

Comment: Are you sure you havent got the inequality the wrong way round? the answer seems to suggest otherwise

Comment: @JustWandering could you please explain the right way to get the answer?

Comment: Usually what I do first is solve for the roots as if it is an equality equation and sketch the graph. Clearly, what you want is the parts of $x$ such that the corresponding $y$ lies above $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

At $ [0,+\infty) $, the inequation is equivalent to $$2-x^2\ge 0$$

the solution set is $$S^+=[0,\sqrt{2}]$$

At $ (-\infty,0] $, it is

$$2-x^2\le 0$$
the solution set is
$$S^-=(-\infty,-\sqrt{2}] $$

the final solution is
$$S=S^-\cup S^+=(-\infty,-\sqrt{2}]\cup [0,\sqrt{2}]$$

Answer (score 0):

For this particular type of problems where you can factorize one side and compare it to $0$, I would suggest making a table. On the top row you have the independent variable ($x$ in this case). Then make columns for all the values of $x$ where the left hand side term is $0$. Add some columns for intermediate values and for $\pm\infty$. Then on each row put one of the terms. Mark where it is $0$ and just put the sign everywhere else. Something like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}x&-\infty&\ &-\sqrt 2&\ &0&\ &\sqrt 2&\ &\infty\\\hline\\x&-&-&-&-&0&+&+&+&+\\\sqrt2+x&-&-&0&+&+&+&+&+&+\\\sqrt2-x&+&+&+&+&+&+&0&-&-\\x(2-x^2)&+&+&0&-&0&+&0&-&-\end{array}$$

I've used here $2-x^2=(\sqrt 2-x)(\sqrt 2+x)$. If you multiply several functions, if one is $0$ then the product is $0$. If the number of negative signs is even then the product is positive, and if the number of negative signs is odd, then the product is negative. So the final answer is $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt 2]\cup[0,\sqrt 2]$. This seems to be the exact opposite of your answer. Please check your original inequality. Plug in $x=10$ for example, and see that it does not verify your solution.